# NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error: method adding extra "/"

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

In my method, I need to call a web service. I have used the following

```
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&parseError]
```

where jsonDictionary is

```
{
  "timeStamp" : "",
  "listOfScratchNotes" : [
    {
      "id" : "13",
      "location" : "reqw",
      "dateOfMeeting" : "23/12/2012",
      "dealers" : "fr"
    }
  ]
}
```

After using the `dataWithJSONObject:` method, my dateOfMeeting: gets converted to `23\/12\/2012`

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dict =      // Dictionary here..

NSData *dataRecvd = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if(!dataRecvd && error){
    NSLog(@"Error creating JSON: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

//NSJSONSerialization converts a URL string from http://... to http:\/\/... remove the extra escapes
Str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRecvd encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
Str = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\/" withString:@"/"];
dataRecvd = [policyStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```